# year is populating 1970 by default in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame in which a DOB column is there which contains DOB as "07011973".When I am trying to convert this column in the date the year value is populating as 1970 by default.

Here is my code:
fico_score["customerInputDateofbirth"]=pd.to_datetime(fico_score["customerInputDateofbirth"],format='%Y/%m/%d').dt.date

output comes as :
1970-01-07

Kindly help me here.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your format into `%d%m%Y`:

```
fico_score["customerInputDateofbirth"]=pd.to_datetime(fico_score["customerInputDateofbirth"],format='%d%m%Y').dt.date
```